# What are the writings of 'devarshi charitha' by Gargeya?

Tags: scripture, mahabharata

In a conversation between Yudhistrira and Bhishma, I encountered the following statements, which occur in a conversation between a guru and disciple

> At the end of every (celestial) yuga (when universal destruction sets
> in) the Vedas and all other scriptures disappear (like the rest). In
> consequence of the grace of the Self-born, the great Rishis, through
> their penances, first re-acquire the lost Vedas and the scriptures.
> The Self-born (Brahman) first acquired the Vedas. Their branches
> called the Angas were first acquired by (the celestial preceptor)
> Vrihaspati. Bhrigu's son (Sukra) first acquired the science of
> morality that is so beneficial for the universe. The science of music
> was acquired by Narada; that of arms by Bharadwaja; **the history of the
> celestial Rishis by Gargya**: that of medicine by the dark-complexioned
> son of Atri. Diverse other Rishis, whose names are connected
> therewith, promulgated diverse other sciences such as Nyaya,
> Vaiseshika, Sankhya, Patanjala, etc.
>
> [[Section 210, Mokshadharma Parva, Santi Parva, The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12b037.htm)

I am aware of the existence of Vedas, Vedangas, Niti-shastras,  Gandharvaveda, Dhanurveda and some others. But, I am unaware of the writings of Gargeya referred to in the quote. What are the writings? Are they available online?